# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver, selenium-docker

I created a **Selenium standalone Firefox docker container** and started the session in Host port:4545
**docker run -d -p 4545:4444 --shm-size 2g selenium/standalone-firefox:3.141.59**
I checked with http://localhost:4545/ if opening or not. It worked fine.

When I am trying to connect through my Selenium code, it is throwing me error as:
[image]

[image]

My sample code as below:
[image]

Please suggest how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the RemoteWebDriver url from http://localhost:4545/wb/hub to http://localhost:4545/wd/hub

Comment: :) No Problem my friend. I am glad that you are able to find out root cause